# ImportError: Cannot import name globalvar

Tags: qgis, python, grass-gis

For those familiar with QGIS with Grass I need help...

I installed QGIS 2.16.1 with Grass 7.0.4 on both a Windows 10 desktop and a Windows 10 laptop.  On the laptop version I use Grass to create a new Mapset.  I I then open the the Grass shell and the curser is at:

*C:\QGIS\bin>*

I add
*C:\QGIS\bin> i.group*

Works fine and opens a new igroup window to work from.

However, I do the exact same setup and input the same on my desktop and I get:

```
C:\QGIS\bin>i.group
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/QGIS/apps/grass/GRASS-~1.4/gui/wxpython/gui_core/forms.py", line  85, in <module>
from core import globalvar

ImportError: cannot import name globalvar
```

I have no idea where to begin to solve this issue as it is no custom script I am working on.  Just the standard QGIS with Grass installation on both machines?

heeeelp!

Comment: So you can open the GRASS gui and run commands (such as **Imagery->Develop Images._Create Groups [i.group]** from the menu on both machines? I think that checking 'echo %PATH%' and 'echo %PYTHONPATH%' might reveal something different between the machines.